# How to get nlapiGetOldRecord() sublist value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to get nlapiGetOldRecord sublist values.

```
var record= nlapiGetOldRecord();
var testCount= record.getLineItemCount('recmachcustrecord_test');
```

The above linecount api is working and output the number of lines. But when i try to get its line item values it's giving following error **"Cannot find function nlapiGetLineItemValue in object nlobjRecord."**. My code.

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= testCount; i++) {
  var name= record.nlapiGetLineItemText('recmachcustrecord_test', 'custrecord_name', i);
  var quantity = record.nlapiGetLineItemValue('recmachcustrecord_test', 'custrecord_qty', i);
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Detail: ', name + ' and ' + quantity);

}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with one of those "recmachcustrecord_" lists.  I was only ever able to get around it by always running the code as admin.  Not sure if that will help you or not.

Comment: No i have diff problem for more detail please see below answer which is correct. @W3BGUY

Comment: lol...  I completely missed that you were trying to use the nlapi* methods.  Yep, that won't work on an object. :)  Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Basically i was trying to get line item text/value using `nlapiGetLineItemText` api and which is not nlobjRecord api. so for sublist nlobjRecord `getLineItemText` api works.

```
 var record= nlapiGetOldRecord();
    var testCount= record.getLineItemCount('recmachcustrecord_test'); 
    for (var i = 1; i <= testCount; i++) {
      var name= record.getLineItemText('recmachcustrecord_test', 'custrecord_name', i);
      var quantity = record.getLineItemValue('recmachcustrecord_test', 'custrecord_qty', i);
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Detail: ', name + ' and ' + quantity);

    }
```